# Adjusting an output of grep in an sh script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Good evening,

I'm trying to grep a list of databases stored within a MYSQL dump but I'd like to adjust some of the settings - I'm unsure how to do so.

The code is currently;

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "What is the cPanel username!"
read cpuser

cd /home/${cpuser}/public_html

sqldump=$(find . -name \*.sql -type f)
sqlversion=$(grep "Server version" ${sqldump})
sqldbs=$(grep "CREATE DATABASE" ${sqldump})

echo "The dump location is"
echo $sqldump
echo "The SQL version is"
echo $sqlversion
echo "The databases in the dump are"
echo $sqldbs
```

The output of that is ( in this example )

```
What is the cPanel username!
domain1mysql4
The dump location is
./test/xxx/database/xxxx.sql
The SQL version is
-- Server version 4.1.14
The databases in the dump are
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `blog` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */; CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `blog1` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */; CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mysql` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
```

I have two questions, ultimately.

Is it possible to only list the databases that it outputs `'blog' 'blog1' 'mysql'` rather than the rest of the line?

Is it also possible to then save those as a variable to be called later in the script?

Output after freddy adjustment

```
sh ./test.sh
enter the cPanel username: domain10mysql4
./home/saiprem/xxxxx/database/xxxx.sql:activesearch
./home/saiprem/xxxxx/database/x.sqxxxxl:alienstats
./home/saiprem/x/database/xxxxxx.sql:anahaw
xxxx./home/saiprem/x/databasxxxe/xxxx.sql:b2
./home/saiprem/x/database/x.sql:beeforumxxx
```

Comment: I find it difficult to parse this: "finds 'blog' 'blog1' 'mysql' rather than the rest of the line?"

Comment: Oh. You want just the quoted database names

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions for this answer:

- Zero or more `*.sql` files might be present in the filesystem
- Calling Bash is allowed, we use it store the database names in an array
- `grep` with Perl-compatible regular expressions (`-P`) is available to not output unwanted parts of a match (`\K`).

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "enter the cPanel username: " cpuser
cd "/home/$cpuser/public_html"

find . -name \*.sql -type f -exec bash -c '
    echo "found $# sql dumps"
    for file; do
        version=$(grep -Poe "-- Server version \K.*" "$file")
        dbnames=( $(grep -Poe "CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\K[^\`]*" "$file") )

        printf "\n          file: %s\n" "$file"
        printf "server version: %s\n" "$version"
        printf "%2s database(s): %s\n" "${#dbnames[*]}" "${dbnames[*]}"

        for dbname in "${dbnames[@]}"; do
            echo "do something with $dbname"
        done
    done
' 'find-sh' {} +
```

Output using two test files:

```
$ ./script.sh 
enter the cPanel username: me
./script.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to /home/me/public_html
found 2 sql dumps

          file: ./dump2.sql
server version: 4.1.14
 1 database(s): test
do something with test

          file: ./dump1.sql
server version: 4.1.14
 3 database(s): blog blog1 mysql
do something with blog
do something with blog1
do something with mysql
```

You can see the that directory `/home/me/public_html` doesn't exist and the script needs error handling.

---

**Edit:**

All database names with filename prefix:

```
$ find . -name \*.sql -type f -exec grep -Poe "CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\K[^\`]*" {} +
./dump2.sql:test
./dump1.sql:blog
./dump1.sql:blog1
./dump1.sql:mysql
```

All database names sorted (add `-u` to sort to remove duplicates):

```
$ find . -name \*.sql -type f -exec grep -hPoe "CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\K[^\`]*" {} + | sort
blog
blog1
mysql
test
```

Comment: Hi Freddy, Thank you for this - however, is there a way to have just a full list of the db's at the end rather than it printing per file? Some of the directories have up to 162 sql files, many with 0 db's and resulting in 5 overall but it takes some time to track back over the script to find them. Ultimately it's a migration project so I need to locate the db's to then be able to import the db's

Comment: Okay, then it might be easier to run `find` and `grep` at the end to only output the db names instead of juggling with bash arrays. See edit.

Comment: Thank you Freddy, I've edited my main post with the results of the command. Just so you understand what I am trying to achieve - I need to find databases that need creating (thus listing them) - but I then need to incorporate a way to say - right, we've found the dump file which contains them - now mysql -u root < dumpfile to import them. The reason I need the db names is to refer back to them later.

Comment: Then add a line `printf "mysql -u root < %s\n" "$(readlink -f $file)"` to the original script which includes the absolute path to the file and remove the second for-loop. You can copy & paste these lines for the import later. And add the second command of my edit to the end of the script to list all databases of each user. If that's not what you want, then tell us how the output should look like.

Comment: Okay makes sense, but I wanted the mysql -u root command to happen automatically. So the above echos the result - I understand that, but how do I reference that (automatically) later

Comment: But how would you run the database imports automatically if you have to decide manually which dumps to choose? You can change the above to the real command, but I fear that's also not correct.

Comment: So all the databases are in the same dump file, the reason I need to know the database names is because I need to alter them after creation to include a prefix - unless there is a way to do that automatically too - do you have discord maybe easier for me to discuss on there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding a prefix is possible, but that's out of the question here and I'm the wrong guy.

Comment: That's why if I find a way to refer back to those DB names I found - I can then make a backup of the db (as it was) - create the new db with the prefix, import the dump from the old name and drop the original db - as the prefix is the $cpuser variable, so that's easy - import from the main dump - somehow refer back to those DB names to select them, dump them, create the new db based on cpuser_dbname, import the dump and remove the original

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to filter the line that outputs the database names through `sed`.

One thing the database names have in common in your output is the "`" quotation.

So you could pipe the line containing the names through the following process:

1. Place a newline after each quotation
2. `Grep` for all lines containing the quotation
3. Replace all newlines with a space
4. Delete the space that I think will follow the opening quotation of each name.

That should output only the names inside the quotations on that line.

Bearing in mind that I'm posting this answer just after 1AM, if I'm reading your script right, and if I'm not being dumb, it should look like this:

```
echo $sqldbs | sed 's/\`/\`\n/' | grep "\`" | sed 's/\n/ /' | sed 's/\` /`/'
```

It's a bit long-winded, but it should get the job done.

If there are any issues with it, let me know.